# what is third party API,plugin and library?

Tags: php, api, plugins

Hi I am new to PHP coding.I always heard the terms **third party API,plugins,library**.Is all are same or exist any difference between third party API and Library.Please help me to get the exact picture about it.Thanks in advance....

Comment: `third party` = `written by somebody else`

Comment: API - generally an online service that you can access from your code; library - an piece of code that you need to download; plug-in - additional downloable code to work with a library or application

Comment: thanks for the quick reply.For clarifying the reply can u please tell me Morris chart includes in which type above ?

Comment: Morris Charts..... you download them, so they're not an online service; and you can use them in your pages without additional software, so they're not a plug-in

Comment: thanks Mark Baker....now i get a clear picture...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can consider 
**Third party Api:** This is what you can't have code with but still you call api and get the response.
**Plugins:** These are the set of code that you have with you, but this can be managed by owner(or update or any change or bug fixing). You also can customized it using hooks and all.
**Library:** These are the set code which you own and then you are the owner and you can make changes.

Comment: Person who has down voted answer can explain what is wrong here so all user can come to know the exact eplaination.